# How to update data in Activity from recycler adapter instantly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

**Hello there! I am developing a shopping application where user can set items quantity and the recycler will show instant pricing according to the quantity.
but the problem I am facing is I cant update the total price section in my Activity.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a Callback like this in your adapter

```
interface OnItemUpdateListener{
void onUpdateTotal(int total)
}
```

Then register that callback in your adapter from your activity, and on click increment or decrement call that callback

```
onItemUpdateListener.onUpdateTotal(total)
```

Then in Your activity you can override onUpdateTotal(int total) method, Set value of total_textview here.